# Javascript background-attachment fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

The CSS `background-attachment: fixed;` does not work on mobiles because it takes a performance hit or something like that.

Is there an alternative for this that fully works on mobile?

I tried this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('div#home').css('background-position', 'left ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

But that was very choppy on my Mac using chrome, so I didn't even bother testing on my iPhone.

I see many plugins for a parallax effect but can't find any that work on mobile. I saw some previous questions on this and other forums but those links were either dead or outdated now.

In our ever advancing world, have apple been bothered to render stuff properly?

Basically...
**Is there a fix to `background-attachment: fixed` that works on all devices including mobile?**

Code from dmoo's link:

```
div#home {
    color: #404040;
/*
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.375) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 0.375) 100%), url(/images/sp-bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
*/
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;

}

div#home:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background: url('/images/sp-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: transform;
}
```

Comment: I used this with success - http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property The will-change is pretty well supported - http://caniuse.com/#search=will-change

Comment: @dmoo i have added the code i am using in my question. It fixed the background image but the bg image was on the entire page and not just the div.

Comment: Anyone know how to achieve the background-fixed on all browsers and devices?